# Customize UINavigationBar back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iOS development. I am creating an application with TableViewController. On that screen I added a navigation bar too. I want the title and sub title,want to customize back button. I use the following code to add the title and sub title.

```
func setTitle(title:String, subtitle:String) -> UIView {
        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 25, 0, 0))


        ....
        let subtitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 54, 0, 0))
       ....
        let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, max(titleLabel.frame.size.width, subtitleLabel.frame.size.width), 95))

        .....

        return titleView
    }
```

Above code working fine. Now I want to customize the back button. My origional design should the following screenshot 
[image]. But my output not simillar it is like the following screenshot [image].

I am also using the following code to change the back button style

```
    navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 224/255, green: 224/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1.0)
 navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back_button")
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backItem!.title = "";
//        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backItem!
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back_button")
```

Why my back button is different. Please someone help me to find out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

set the navigation bar button item  tint colour to white or default... and check 
may be it will solve your problem

if you are using story board then open storyboard - Then Click the view where you have set the navigation bar image - click on that image - open attribute inspector - set the tint colour and if you have set it programatically then

```
 self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
 self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: if you are using story board then open storyboard - Then Click the view where you have set the navigation bar image - click on that image - open attribute inspector - set the tint colour and if you have set it programatically then                                                   self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black &
 self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

Comment: I am not using storyboard for this. I tried your code not working.

Comment: have you edited this....   navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 224/255, green: 224/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1.0)   with the above code...